# Timestamp gmapping

Tags: slam, navigation, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I tried to run gmapping on a robot and I have trouble with the synchronization of LaserScan messages and tf messages. I get this kind of warning:

```
[ WARN] [1343039900.709215634]: Failed to compute odom pose, skipping scan (Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1343039900.708730672 but the latest data is at time 1343039900.680892204, when looking up transform from frame [/base_link] to frame [/odom])
```

And the map doesn't update
Most of the time, the first scan create the map, but then I only get this warning and the map doesn't update

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39488/timestamp-gmapping/) by [Seb P](https://answers.ros.org/users/2901/seb-p/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kshitij](https://answers.ros.org/users/1481/kshitij/) on 2012-07-22**:
check this thread out: http://answers.ros.org/question/32399/slam_gmapping-registering-first-scan-problem/

**Comment by [Seb P](https://answers.ros.org/users/2901/seb-p/) on 2012-07-23**:
The warning is :Failed to compute odom pose, skipping scan (Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1343039900.708730672 but the latest data is at time 1343039900.680892204, when looking up transform from frame [/base_link] to frame [/odom])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cannot see any warning message in your post...

And what do you mean by "And the map doesn't update Most of the time...". Did you drive a robot around for a while? As far as i know, the map does not update with every observation but only after the robot having driven for some distance...

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0